# how to change the background color in maximo?

Tags: css, maximo

I would like to change the background color for the entire maximo application whichever page is opened with in the application?

[image]

Currently the background color is white, I want to change it to something else.
Which css or jsp files I need to change?
we are using old maximo 6.2.3 version.

Thanks in advance.Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Go to `<maximo root>\applications\maximo\maximouiweb\webmodule\webclient\skins\css` Find the maximo.css file and check for `body { background-color: }` Replace the color value.

Comment: @ManojKumar I have maximo.css file in Maxtest\applications\maximo\maximouiweb\webmodule\webclient\css folder, but there is nothing like you have mentioned.

Comment: Can you post the contents of the file and is the application hosted locally?

Comment: No the application is not hosted locally

Comment: Give the link of the website you are working on, I will find out the solution for you.

Comment: It cannot be possible..I am working on a client system.I have posted the contents of maximo.css file in the question..please take a look at it

Comment: Open your developer tools and inspect the body element. Find out the file URL it is located in.

Comment: @manoj, you should post your first comment as an Answer to the question, so you can be given credit for it. When you do, you should also mention that your answer is based on Maximo 7+.

Comment: Siva GV, did you get it working by editing maximo.css? If so, you should post the answer to your question. Don't leave us hanging like this! ;-)

Comment: @Preacher I am not sure if it worked for OP :)

Comment: @ManojKumar, I'm sure it did not, given the other comments here. But it could work for others who want to do the same in Maximo 7+. And the bit about the `body` may be what he had to look for in the maximo.css for Maximo 6, which would be part marks -- maybe enough for OP to call it "the" answer. :-) At any rate, the phrasing of your first comment was that of an answer, not of a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it, but I think the file you want to edit is `<maximo_home>\applications\maximo\maximouiweb\webmodule\webclient\controls\clientarea\control.css`.